# Reverse / Mirror 64 bits with a look up table in C

Tags: arrays, c, bit-manipulation, bit, lookup-tables

I am trying to implement a function that:

- creates a look-up table of 256 reversed integers (*i.e.* `table[1]` will contain 10000000<sub>2</sub>).
- receives an 8-byte value which is split to 1-byte chunks.
- looks up each chunk of 8 bits to get its reversed bits, and
- concatenates the bits and assigns the concatenated value to an 8-byte variable which will be the returned value of the function.

**My Code:**

```
#include <stddef.h>


typedef size_t bitsarr_ty;  /* Assuming 64-bit system - size of 8 bytes */

typedef enum
{
    NOT_INITIALIZED,
    INITIALIZED
} mirrored_lut_status_ty;

static int mirrored_bits_lut[256] = {0};



bitsarr_ty BitArrayMirror(bitsarr_ty bitarr);

mirrored_lut_status_ty mirrored_lut_status = NOT_INITIALIZED;

/******************************* InitMirroredLUT **********************/

void InitMirroredLUT()
{
    size_t integer_value = 0;

    for (integer_value = 0; integer_value < 256; ++integer_value)
    {
        mirrored_bits_lut[integer_value] = BitArrayMirror(integer_value);
    }
}

/******************************* BitArrayMirror **********************/

bitsarr_ty BitArrayMirror(bitsarr_ty bitarr)
{
    size_t curr_bit_index = 0;  
    bitsarr_ty mirrored_bitarr = 0; 

    for (curr_bit_index = 0; curr_bit_index < 64; ++curr_bit_index) 
    { 
        if((bitarr & (1UL << curr_bit_index)))
        {
            mirrored_bitarr |= 1UL << ((64 - 1) - curr_bit_index); 
        }  
    } 

    return(mirrored_bitarr); 
}

bitsarr_ty BitArrayMirrorLUT(bitsarr_ty bitarr)
{
    bitsarr_ty mirrored_bitarr = 0;

    if (NOT_INITIALIZED == mirrored_lut_status)
    {
        InitMirroredLUT();
        mirrored_lut_status = INITIALIZED;
    }

    mirrored_bitarr = mirrored_bits_lut[bitarr & 0xff] << 56 |
        mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 8) & 0xff] << 48 |         
        mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 16) & 0xff] << 40 |
        mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 24) & 0xff] << 32 |         
        mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 32) & 0xff] << 24 |
        mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 40) & 0xff] << 16 |
        mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 48) & 0xff] << 8 |            
        mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 56) & 0xff];

    return (mirrored_bitarr);
}
```

It compiles and runs with the wrong output.

For the following input:

```
0000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000010000000000000000
```

I am getting the following output:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and the following errors:

```
In function ‘BitArrayMirrorLUT’:
source/bit_array.c:321:53: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  321 |  mirrored_bitarr = mirrored_bits_lut[bitarr & 0xff] << 56 |
      |                                                     ^~
source/bit_array.c:322:49: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  322 |         mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 8) & 0xff] << 48 |
      |                                                 ^~
source/bit_array.c:323:50: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   |         mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 16) & 0xff] << 40 |
      |                                                  ^~
source/bit_array.c:324:50: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   |         mirrored_bits_lut[(bitarr >> 24) & 0xff] << 32 |
```

What are my mistakes here?

Comment: Your lookup table stores signed ints, usually 32 bits wide. If you want to shift them for more than 31 bits you should convert it to `bitsarr_ty`. That's what the warnings are telling you. (By the way, `<stdint.h>` has integers of specified widths such as `uint64_t`, which might be useful here.)

Comment: `BitArrayMirror` shifts too much. You are using it to initialize a table of eight-bit reversals, but it attempts to reverse in a field of 64 bits.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't help when I try to cast it to `(bitsarr_ty)` in the beginning of each line (of the last lines).

Comment: It fixes the warning, doesn't it? That's what my comment was about. And it was just a comment, not an answer. Tsanisl has answered what your real issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Because when computing mirrored_bits_lut you reverse 8 bit number as 64bit one. All important bits are ignored when converting to 32bit int

Comment: oh, got it. so should I make the lookup table as 64 elements to fix this?

Comment: @NoobCoder: No. Make the table a table of `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` elements and change the `64` in `BitArrayMirror` to `8` in each of the two places it appears. In `BitArrayMirrorLUT`, change each `mirrored_bits_lut[…]` to `(bitsarr_ty) mirrored_bits_lut[…]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, it works! But.. Is there an option to make it work while keeping the `BitArrayMirror` option singular for both `64` and `8` bits parameters insead of copying it and changing the `64` to `8?`?